# Is there an api endpoint to list files in private chat?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am looking for a way to get the number of files in a private chat using the Microsoft Graph API.

Currently I can get the messages from private chat using:

```
beta/users/{user_id}/chats/{chat_id}/messages
```

Another API is the 'List children of a driveItem' - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http to get the number of files for a **channel** - that looks like this:

```
/teams/{team_id}/channels/{channel_id}/messages
```

And get a response like this:

```
value ': [{
' id ': ' 123456'},
' user ': {' displayName ': ' Username ',
' folder ': {' childCount ': 9}]
```

And I can access the **childCount** parameter

Problem is, that it receives only **team ID** - and not **chat ID**.

So I am looking for an API that just receive the chat ID and send in response the information, just the the 'List children of a driveItem' API

If there is a way to get the drive-id of a private chat it would be good as well since I will use the same list children API and it should work, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Chats threads don't have a drive as only teams have a drive associated with them. Are you looking for number of files shared in a chat thread? Its unclear what you want because the response in the question does not seem to come from `/teams/{team_id}/channels/{channel_id}/messages`. Please edit the question to be more clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chats threads don't have a drive as only teams have a drive associated with them.
However you can get the list of all chat messages which contains attachments[] for files shared in private chat using below API:

beta/users/{user_id}/chats/{chat_id}/messages

So here ChatId is available along with the attachments[] like below:

"attachments": [
{
"id": "4a000672-3234-4306-8c01-b6e6fea43f22",
"contentType": "reference",
"contentUrl": "https://m365x645306.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/Shared Documents/Test/My-Tasks.csv",
"content": null,
"name": "My-Tasks.csv",
"thumbnailUrl": null
}
],

So based on the attachments, you can get the number of files attached in this private chat along with it's SharePoint content URL.